# How to apply WebExtensions content_scripts to Firefox view-source: pages?

Tags: firefox-addon-webextensions

I've written an add-on which [highlights insecure links](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/insecure-links-highlighter/), but [its `content_scripts`](https://github.com/l0b0/insecure-links-highlighter/blob/7e848dd49cf2450474a2d0307ea572791563aa95/manifest.json#L8-L21) is not applied to "view-source: pages.

There's no information in the add-on debugging console, and none of the [permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) look relevant, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

This seems similar to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47503841/96588) except I'm not trying to *open* view-source: pages and I don't get any error messages.

Obviously if there's some way to apply the script to "view-source:" pages using a different mechanism than `content_scripts` that would also be great.

Answer (score 0):

The permission

```
"<all_urls>"
```

in your manifest.json includes only HTTP and HTTPS. It does not include internal pages and protocols like view-source. As a result of this, content scripts can only be added to HTTP and HTTPS pages.

Comment: It includes other protocols such as FTP as well, but yes, I know. Hence the question.

Comment: There is no way to include the view-source protocol as an extension developer, that's what I tried to say.

Comment: Fair point, amended to be an "I'm looking for a solution, not necessarily tied to `content_scripts`" question.

Comment: And that is what I say as well. There is no solution right now.